# Python BeautifulSoup returned an empty list with find_all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make an OSINT tool and I need some IP infos, there's the code i've used :

```py
def ip_infos():
    url = "https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/"
    ip = input("Adresse IP à rechercher : ")
    url_completed = url + ip
    y = r.get(url_completed)
    ip_check_soup = BeautifulSoup(y.content, features="html5lib")
    infos = ip_check_soup.find_all('p', class_='information')
    print(infos)
```

I already tried many times to search on stackoverflow but didn't found any convenient solution...

It everytimes returns an emptylist as "[]"

If someone know a solution or met this error before... Thx

I already tried to search on the internet

Comment: That page depends on javascript.  But you're using `requests` to fetch the page content, which does not understand javascript.

Comment: It also looks like a highly dubious website. If I were you I'd try to find another (safer) way to achieve your objective (whatever that is)

Answer (score 0):

I would instead use **urllib3** package to open ipinfo.io and parse its json output based on the given IP. It returns location data, as well as the routers organisation and even postal code/zip code .Here is my implementation:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

ip='YourIPhere'#Can be IPv4 or IPv6

url=f'http://ipinfo.io/{ip}/json'
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)
org=data['org']
city = data['city']
country=data['country']
region=data['region']
loc=data['loc']
postal=data['postal']
latlong=str(loc).split(',')
lat,long=latlong[0],latlong[1]
timezone=data['timezone']
hostname=data['hostname']
```

This Code opens up ipinfo.io in its json format(which returns data about the given ip) with your chosen IP in the url, and parses its JSON output into variables. If you need, you can go to ipinfo.io/json to get IP data about the local computers IP if your program is ran client side.
Anyways,here is the pip command to install URLLIB (python3.X) for the urlopen() function:

```
pip install urllib3
```

Hope this helps!

> Edit: You can make an account on ipinfo.io if you want to access their api with more features/data, but i believe the normal json response is good enough